# How long should Delete Identical take on 3.25 GB feature class of polygons with spatial index?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, performance

I have a 3.25 GB feature class of polygons with a spatial index. I am using the delete identical tool comparing the shape and one other field which contains a text string of 9 characters.

The tool has been running for 13 days and I suspect it has crashed/got stuck. ArcCatalog says it is still running as does task manager. As there is no progress bar is there a way to estimate how long this task should take?

I am using 64 bit geoprocessing from ArcGIS 10.1 for Desktop with 16GB RAM 3.4 GHz 6 core processor

Comment: I would imagine that arcmap has got into some memory issue as 3.2gb for a feature class is pretty large. Why not preselect your features to reduce the number of tests it has to make? For example can you select a sub set of the data say by region as your duplication would never happen across regions?

Comment: I would open task manager and see how system resources are being used.  You can get a pretty good idea if your CPU is working or hung.

Comment: If it helps, I've had a process run 15 days, and it still worked.  I was calculating a Near process with I believe ~4 million points.  Now, when I ran my process I did not have the specs as you do, plus I was a moron and left my SQL Server instance running which I'm sure slowed it down a bit.  Honestly, I wouldn't touch it.  It may be tempting after two weeks, but let's face it, you're in this far.  As @Hornbydd suggests, breaking the process into regions could help but unless you have a separate machine/license to do that, I would just let it ride.

Comment: if the process memory for 64bit processing is changing size in task manager the process is still running... wait it out. Have had processes take 6 weeks in the past (near tool as above).

Answer (score 0):

The only attempts to answer so far have been via comments:

- @Hornbydd suggested:

> I would imagine that arcmap has got into some memory issue as 3.2gb
>   for a feature class is pretty large. Why not preselect your features
>   to reduce the number of tests it has to make? For example can you
>   select a sub set of the data say by region as your duplication would
>   never happen across regions?

- @Aaron♦ suggested:

> I would open task manager and see how system resources are being used.
>   You can get a pretty good idea if your CPU is working or hung.

- @evv_gis suggested:

> If it helps, I've had a process run 15 days, and it still worked. I
>   was calculating a Near process with I believe ~4 million points. Now,
>   when I ran my process I did not have the specs as you do, plus I ...
>   left my SQL Server instance running which I'm sure slowed it down a
>   bit. Honestly, I wouldn't touch it. It may be tempting after two
>   weeks, but let's face it, you're in this far. As @Hornbydd suggests,
>   breaking the process into regions could help but unless you have a
>   separate machine/license to do that, I would just let it ride.

- @Mapperz suggested:

> if the process memory for 64bit processing is changing size in task
>   manager the process is still running... wait it out. Have had
>   processes take 6 weeks in the past (near tool as above).